# How to give an independent values in CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, figure

I have this html mark up:

```
<div>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
  <figure></figure>
</div>
```

and some CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative; 
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is push aside so that each element is arranged separately from each other, so when the first has a margin of 0 to the second has a margin of 100px, while second has a margin of 100px third will have a margin of 200px;

and jQuery:

```
var circle = $('figure'),
    f_circle = content_container.find(circle).first(),
    n_circle = f_circle.next();

    var circle_width = circle.width();

        var circle_separate = function(){
            n_circle = f_circle;
            for(var i=0; i< options.elements_number; i++) {
                n_circle.each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'margin-left': +circle_width * (options.elements_number -2) + 10 * (options.elements_number - 2) + 'px'
                    });
                })
            }
        }
```

And if I have more than 3 elements to behave more similarly, last shied away from before last.

To have this in ouptut:
[image]
Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

;You can use `jQuery.each()` to cycle through them all, the `each` functionality gives you the position in the array of the current element and you just need to multiply that by your desired width

```
var circle = $('figure');
var circle_width = circle.width();

var circle_separate = function(){
    circle.each(function(idx){
        $(this).css('margin-left',(idx * (circle_width +10))+'px');    
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in numerous ways, you can do it either with CSS or with javascript.

In your code, the figure elements are position: absolute, and margin doesn't matter in absolute elements because they can be placed anywhere within your div using top and left and they don't affect elements before or after them.

Try to write your css like this:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want you can specify individual margins from each other in CSS like this:

```
figure:first-child { margin-right: 10px; }
figure:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 30px; }
figure:nth-child(3) { margin-right: 50px; }
```

If you want to make to use jquery to do this and have them as absolute, you can use jquery's each() function

I would do something like this (since you can't use margins in absolute elements that have top/left specified):

```
var prevLeft = 0;
var prevWidth = 0;
$("figure").each(function(idx, elem){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.css({ left: prevLeft+prevWidth+10 });

    prevLeft = $this.offset().left;
    prevWidth = $this.width();
});
```